# Content length limitation in http requests to pod ip and port

Tags: http, kubernetes

**Env:**

```
# kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                  STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION          CONTAINER-RUNTIME
km12-01               Ready    master   26d   v1.13.0   10.42.140.154   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS   4.17.0-041700-generic   docker://17.6.2
km12-02               Ready    master   26d   v1.13.0   10.42.104.113   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS   4.17.0-041700-generic   docker://17.6.2
km12-03               Ready    master   26d   v1.13.0   10.42.177.142   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS   4.17.0-041700-generic   docker://17.6.2
prod-k8s-node002      Ready    node     25d   v1.13.0   10.42.78.21     <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS   4.17.0-041700-generic   docker://17.3.2
prod-k8s-tmpnode005   Ready    node     24d   v1.13.0   10.42.177.75    <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS   4.17.0-041700-generic   docker://17.3.2
```

calico v3.3.1

**What Happen:**

I have a deployment, with 2 pods scheduled on `prod-k8s-node002` and `prod-k8s-tmpnode005`. Just like this:

```
# kubectl -n gitlab-prod get pods -o wide
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP                NODE                  NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
api-monkey-76489bd8c9-7gbkt               1/1     Running   0          35m     192.244.199.37    prod-k8s-node002      <none>           <none>
api-monkey-76489bd8c9-w2zrs               1/1     Running   0          55m     192.244.124.240   prod-k8s-tmpnode005   <none>           <none>
```

Now I curl each pod from a master node, say it is `km12-01`:

```
# # wait 0ms, response a json string, which has a property named 'data', it is a string, which is '1' repeated by 1000 times
# curl -v '192.244.124.240:3000/health/test?ms=0&content=1&repeat=1000'
*   Trying 192.244.124.240...
* Connected to 192.244.124.240 (192.244.124.240) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /health/test?ms=0&content=1&repeat=1000 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.244.124.240:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 1011
< ETag: W/"3f3-oUOV2TWikka+Y8l16Cqo/Q"
< Date: Sat, 08 Dec 2018 20:12:26 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host 192.244.124.240 left intact
{"data":"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"}

# curl -v '192.244.199.37:3000/health/test?ms=0&content=1&repeat=1000'
*   Trying 192.244.199.37...
* Connected to 192.244.199.37 (192.244.199.37) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /health/test?ms=0&content=1&repeat=1000 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.244.199.37:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 1011
< ETag: W/"3f3-oUOV2TWikka+Y8l16Cqo/Q"
< Date: Sat, 08 Dec 2018 20:15:16 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host 192.244.199.37 left intact
{"data":"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"}
```

Good, both work.

So if I make a longer response body (2000 bytes), what will happen?

```
# curl -v '192.244.124.240:3000/health/test?ms=0&content=1&repeat=2000'
*   Trying 192.244.124.240...
* Connected to 192.244.124.240 (192.244.124.240) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /health/test?ms=0&content=1&repeat=2000 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.244.124.240:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Unfortunately, the connection was hanging on and then reset by peer after couple minutes. But it works on the host of the requested pod.

Curl a pod from its host:

```
# curl -v '192.244.124.240:3000/health/test?ms=0&content=1&repeat=2000'
*   Trying 192.244.124.240...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 192.244.124.240 (192.244.124.240) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /health/test?ms=0&content=1&repeat=2000 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.244.124.240:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
>
{"data":"11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"}< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 2011
< ETag: W/"7db-ViIL+fXpsfh/YwmlqDHSsQ"
< Date: Sat, 08 Dec 2018 20:22:55 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
{ [2011 bytes data]
100  2011  100  2011    0     0   440k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  490k
* Connection #0 to host 192.244.124.240 left intact
```

The other one is in the same situation.

**Summary:**

I tried many times, and found a interesting and strange thing: If I request a pod from any other node (except the host of the pod), the response body cannot be longer than 1140 bytes. Otherwise, the connection will hang on.

**My problem:**

How it happen? And how can I break this limitation?

Comment: I would suspect mtu problems. Do you know what is the infrastructure topology of your setup? I would suggest to do some testing with ping and different payload sizes and tracepath to confirm whether it is mtu related.

Comment: That is too much, I have posted an answer, FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like to be an [MTU issue](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/1709).

Answer (score 0):

This is the kubeadm-1.12.0 initialization file：

```
# cat kubeadm-init.yaml

apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1alpha3
controlPlaneEndpoint: 10.42.79.210:6443
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.12.0
networking:
  podSubnet: 192.244.0.0/16
  serviceSubnet: 192.96.0.0/16
apiServerCertSANs:
- 10.42.140.154
- 10.42.104.113
- 10.42.177.142
- km12-01
- km12-02
- km12-03
- 127.0.0.1
- localhost
- 10.42.79.210
etcd:
  external:
    endpoints:
    - https://10.42.140.154:2379
    - https://10.42.104.113:2379
    - https://10.42.177.142:2379
    caFile: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem
    certFile: /etc/etcd/ssl/etcd.pem
    keyFile: /etc/etcd/ssl/etcd-key.pem
    dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
clusterDNS:
- 192.96.0.2
---
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
mode: "ipvs"
```

We use an external etcd cluster, and the underlying network uses IPVS rather than iptables. We did an upgrade from 1.12.0 to 1.13.0.

```
# kubeadm upgrade apply 1.13.0
```

You can use this to test, and we're the ones that came up after the upgrade. @Adam Otto

There are some IPVS errors as follows：

[kube-proxy logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbuA8.png)